# Weblogic(14.1) spring boot application issue when click on start button

Tags: spring-boot, server, datasource, weblogic14c

[image: putty log]

Error: Attempt to set connection harvestable to false but the connection is already closed.

have checked the database credentials and it was fine.

restart the node manager that is also fine.

when deployement there is no error regarding data source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicates the datasource being used has stale connections. This could happen when the back end Database has been restarted and the WebLogic server is still using the old connection to connect to the database.

**SOLUTION**

Enable Test Connections On Reserve. When Test Connections On Reserve is enabled, when your application requests a connection from the data source, WebLogic Server tests the connection using the query specified in Test Table Name before giving the connection to the application.

To enable Test Connections On Reserve, login to the Weblogic Admin Console -> Navigate to the Data Source's Configuration -> Connection Pool -> (Advanced) -> check "Test Connections On Reserve"